# Log4j in tomcat8 not showing logs

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat8

This is mt Log4j:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, CA, FA
log4j.appender.CA=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CA.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.CA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.FA=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/Z2.log
log4j.appender.FA.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.FA.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FA.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%-5p] [%c:%L]: %m%n
log4j.logger.com.datastax.driver.core=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.dcf=DEBUG
```

Now i am using tomcat8, befor i was using tomcat7 it works great, and save the log file under /var/log/tomcat7/logs/Z2.log

After i uninstall tomcat7 and install tomcat8, i can't find the z1.log file.

Comment: are you using the same war file or something changed? do you have log4j jar in it? which version? where is your log4j.properties located?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni, Yes iam using the same war. Yes i have log4j jar in it(log4j-1.2.17). log4j.properties  located no where, it suppose extract it from the war file. I forgot to mention i am using Maven build

Comment: Hello, have you found the solution of your problem ? I am experimenting the same issue

Answer (score 3):

```
log4j.appender.FA.File=${catalina.base}/logs/Z2.log
```

I don't have enough reputation to comment but is 'CATALINA_BASE' being set as an environmental property?
ie either inferred from 'CATALINA_HOME' or explicitly set?

What happens when you enable debugging for log4j?
This may show why the log file is not being created etc

What I generally do is leave the container logging as it stands but use log4j in any web / EE apps. By doing this, container logging will work with no changes and any web / EE apps are independent ie it is easier to change web / EE containers if necessary.

For Tomcat 8, the native logging library is 'JULI' which implements several key elements of the java.util.logging API.

The following configuration works for

- Tomcat 8.0.30
- jdk1.8.0_66
- log4j 2.5

**[web-app-name] / WEB-INF / lib**

```
commons-logging-l.2.jar 
log4j-api-2.5.jar       
log4j-core-2.5.jar      
log4j-jcl-2.5.jar
```

**[web-app-name] / WEB-INF / classes / log4j.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
   <Properties>
      <Property name="LOG_FILE_PATH">${sys:catalina.home}/logs</Property>
      <Property name="PATTERN_JBOSS" >%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %m%n</Property>
      <Property name="PATTERN_TOMCAT">%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %m%n</Property>
      <Property name="PATTERN"       >${PATTERN_JBOSS}</Property>
   </Properties>

   <Appenders>
      <Console name="console">
         <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN_TOMCAT}"/>
      </Console>

      <RollingFile name="daily-file" fileName   ="${LOG_FILE_PATH}/globaltrax.log"
                                     filePattern="${LOG_FILE_PATH}/globaltrax-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
         <PatternLayout pattern="${PATTERN_JBOSS}"/>
         <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
      </RollingFile>
   </Appenders>

   <Loggers>
      <Root level="WARN">
         <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      </Root>

      <logger name="lpms.web.PurchaseOrderAction" level="TRACE">
         <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
      </logger>

      <logger name="lpms.web.PurchaseOrderAction" level="TRACE">
         <AppenderRef ref="daily-file"/>
      </logger>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This defines one console logger and one daily log file logger which is typical.

Note that ‘CATALINA_HOME’ must be set as a ‘system’ environmental variable - this is used in the line:

```
<Property name="LOG_FILE_PATH">${sys:catalina.home}/logs</Property>
```